# c++ recursive iterable access

Tags: c++, recursion

I am writing a recursive function that takes an iterable of an iterable of an.... of some base type.  Signature something like `<template typename RandomAccessIterator> void recursive_function(RandomAccessIterator rai);`My problem is that if an intermediate iterable is, say, a vector, I will need some code like `recursive_function((*rai).begin())`, whereas if an intermediate iterable is an array, I would use `recursive_function(*rai)`

Is there some way to make these two things compatible with each other?

Answer (score 2):

You want `recursive_function(std::begin(*rai))`.